# how to change default CSS by using emotion/css

Tags: css, emotion

I want to change design of this particular scrollbar which is commonly used by all  in the application. But on this particular page we don't want that.

Code for default CSS:

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                background-color:  #216e7a;
                width: 6px;
                height: 69px;
                border-top: 1px;
                border-top-color: #394245;
                border-top-style: solid;
            }
```

I want to change it using emotion/css so far I did this but nothing is happening,

```
const noScrollBar = css
 div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:red,
    width:20%,
    overflow: scroll;
}
;

<div className={noScrollBar} > ....
```

Any suggestions, I am new to CSS selectors

Comment: Hi, Is that React?

Comment: yes it is React

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `css module` with the styling:

```css
.myClassName {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.myClassName::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: silver;
    width: 10px;
}
.myClassName::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:red;
}
```

Then import it in your code:

```js
import myStyles from './my-styles.module.css'

<div className={myStyles.myClassName} > ....
```

You can also use a simple css (not module):

```js
import './my-styles.css'

<div className={'myClassName'} > ....
```

Comment: I did the same but it somehow still does not work

Comment: Please, be more precise.

Comment: ```
 
    .myClassName::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{
        display:none
    }
```

then in code

````
import styles from './style/Scrollbar.module.css'

return (
  <div orientation={orientation} className={styles.myClassName}>

Comment: You have to add a style to `.myClassName::-webkit-scrollbar` and in `.myClassName` add `overflow:hidden` and `overflow-y:scroll` (I supose you want a vertical scroll). Don't forget that the div must have an absolute `height` or `max-height`. See an example of the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=OwFhNhUEw6):

Comment: Also what if my div is a react native View ? i can then use <View syle={syles.myClassName} /> ??

Comment: View is a div. So It should. I'm not familiarized with React native, but from the docs: [View is a container that supports layout with flexbox, style, some touch handling, and accessibility controls](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view)